# Update a value outside a class and keep it alive in C#?

Tags: c#, class, variables

Well I struggle with a basical scope problem (in my opinion), I'd like to update my variable solution from outside and keep it alive (in the class CProperties) to pass it in my dictionnary so I keep the same key for different value.

ps : I must keep a Dictionary<string, string>() format (for an Api) (yes I would prefer string, string[])

pps: I come from C++

What's would be the right way to do this ?

```
public static class CProperties
{
   public static string solution { get; set; }
            
   static public Dictionary<string, string> product = new Dictionary<string, string>()
   {
       { "product_name", solution}
   };
}
static void mycrazyFunc()
{   
            // I skip the Database connection and everything
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
        
             if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
             {
                 foreach (DataRow rows in dt.Rows)
                 {
                     dynamic JsonObj = new ExpandoObject();
            
                     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(rows["Product"].ToString()))
                     {
                        CProperties.solution = rows["Product"].ToString(); // Got the value !
                        JsonObj.custom_fields = CProperties.product;       // Lost the value ! 
                                                                           // {"product_name", "null"}
                     }
                 }
             }
}
```

Comment: You didn't lose the value, it was never placed into `product`. When `product` is initialized, `solution` is `null`; that's what goes into the dictionary, not a reference to the `solution` property. Changing `solution` doesn't change `product["product_name"]` (not the way you have it here, anyway).

Comment: Explain outside in your case, outside class, outside process, outside machine, what exactly you need provide many more details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have the setter and getter read/write to/from the dictionary itself:

```
public static class CProperties
{
   public static string solution 
   { 
     get{ return product["product_name"]; }
     set{ product["product_name"] = value; }
   }
            
   static public Dictionary<string, string> product = new Dictionary<string, string>()
   {
       { "product_name", null}
   };
}
```

or have the dictionary built on demand

```
public static class CProperties
{
   public static string solution { get; set; }
            
   static public Dictionary<string, string> product => new Dictionary<string, string>()
   {
       { "product_name", solution}
   };
}
```

Either will work for you.

---

But all that aside, your question was

> What's would be the right way to do this ?

Arguably the *right* way to do this is get rid of `CProperties` altogether as it serves no real purpose and just set the dictionary directly:

```
JsonObj.custom_fields = new Dictionary<string,string>{ 
       ["product_name"] = rows["Product"].ToString() 
};
```

Comment: This is absolutely what I was looking for. Since it's called from an endless loop the first option looks better to me for the memory management but maybe less secured from a C++ point of view lol. Thx anyway =)

Comment: @Designart I dont know if your initial code was somewhat contrived but to me it looks like `CProperties` has no use at all and you should just be setting `JsonObj.custom_fields` to a new dictionary. `JsonObj.custom_fields = new Dictionary<string,string>{ ["product_name"] = rows["Product"].ToString() };`

Comment: Actually yes, you're right. The initial idea was to not duplicate the code since I had to call it from different methods (that's why this is maybe not really secured to set something from different place) to send the dictionary as input to the Api. But in the end I may have only one method